# Вопрос по JSoup парсеру

Tags: java, jsoup

С помощью JSoup вытягиваю из страницы блоки с классом **b-user-generated**

```
<span class="b-user-generated">
    <span class="b-icon-nation b-icon-nation__china mceNonEditable" title="Китай">‌</span>
    <span class="b-icon-type b-icon-type__heavytank mceNonEditable" title="Тяжёлый танк">‌</span>
    VIII 112, слот
</span>
```

Как из данного блока вытянуть строку **VIII 112, слот**?
Во всех блоках строки произвольные, в некоторых их может быть больше трех.

Comment: просто найти данный элемент и у него взять text() не пробовал?

Comment: Простите пожалуйста за комментарий не имеющий отношения к вопросу. Я как раз пытаюсь помощью JSoup вытянуть из страницы блоки с каким либо классом. не могли бы вы поделиться решение?

Comment: @Денис
HTML:
    <!DOCTYPE html>    
    <html>    
    <head>    
    </head>    
    <body>    

<div class="cities">
<h2>London</h2>
</div>

'<div class="cities">'
'<h2>Paris</h2>'
'</div>'
''
'<div class="cities">'
'<h2>Tokyo</h2>'
'</div>'
''
'</body>'
'</html>'
Java парсинг html из String:
'Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html); // html - это String с кодом выше
Elements elements = doc.select("div.cities"); // Тег div класс cities'
Или для парсинга страницы из интернета:
'Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get(); // url - String ссылка на страницу
Elements elements = doc.select("div.cities");'

Comment: @AnatoliySamokisha большое спасибо за помощь. сегодня я уже разобрался с этим. не могли бы посмотреть мой вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/446295/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8