# Парсить каждый блок по отдельности

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Есть сайт с разметкой вида

```
<div class="info"><img src="forest.png" alt="" /> Тут статья о природе</div>
<div class="info"><img src="animals.png" alt="" /> О животных - статья</div>
<div class="info"><img src="other.png" alt="" /> Еще одна статья</div>
```

таких блоков примерно 15штук.
Мне нужно спарсить каждый блок отдельно. Начиная с первого и заканчмвая последним(15-тым).
Вот код с помощью которого я пытаюсь это сделать:

```
//Парсим
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://site.ru").get();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            name = doc.title();
            Elements my_a = doc.select("div.info");
            for (Element temp : my_a)
            my_number = temp.text();
            System.out.println("Статья: " + my_number);
        }
    }).start();
```

С помощью этого кода удается только парсить и вывести один блок, последний.

Comment: ctrl-alt-I и понаблюдайте за отступами. особенно в районе `for` и ниже.

Comment: @YuraIvanov не понял вас

Comment: в цикле выполняется только  `my_number = temp.text();` печать выполняется после цикла, один раз. вы забыли фигурные скобки до `my_number=` и после `println`. Если вы бы формтировали код, например автоматически, увидели бы, что `println` вне цикла.

Comment: @YuraIvanov спасибо. работает. но это не совсем то что мне нужно. я хотел чтоб для каждого блока `info` можно было создать свою переменную, типа my_number1 = temp.text(); и тд

Comment: @YuraIvanov на каждую статью я создам отдельный компонент. и выведу все эти статьи на экран, оформлю их по своему усмотрению

Comment: в цикле не хватает фигурных скобок, обозначивающих начало и конец блока.

Answer (score 0):

У вас вот здесь не хватало фигурных скобок (ставте их всегда, даже когда одно выражение в цикле), исправил:

```
for (Element temp : my_a) {
    my_number = temp.text();
    System.out.println("Статья: " + my_number);
}
```