# Не могу пропарсить сайт

Tags: java, парсер, jsoup

```
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class AppStarter {
    public static  void  main(String[] args){

        String url = "https://www.gismeteo.ru/weather-karakol-5209/tomorrow/";
       // String url2 = "https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/438893/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-jsoup-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83?noredirect=1&lq=1";

        Document page = Parser.getPage(url);

        //System.out.println(page);

        Elements divwt = page.select("div.f0f72d12673.aa53f1ceb62");

        System.out.println(divwt.size());

    }
}
```

Результат 0, пожалуйста помогите

Comment: `Elements divwt = page.select("div");` - _только тогда находит блоки div_

Comment: У Гисметео есть API. Честно заплатите им и не придётся парсить. https://www.gismeteo.ru/b2b/

Comment: Я учусь вообще парсить сайты, хочу научиться вынимать информацию, но в основном идут блоки на современных сайтах

Comment: версия библиотеки jsoup 1.11.2 если что :)